How can I write a single pattern for replacement for a nonlinear change of variables
I have a polynomial in say a,b, and c, and I want this to be in terms of x,y, and z where a^(i_)*b^(j_)*c^(k_) ->x^(i+j+k+1)*y^(i+k+1)*z^(k+1), but if I try to use this rule in ReplaceAll, the pattern recognition misses things like a*b*c which should get replaced with x^4*y^3*z^2. I see that in the former expression, using TreeForm, that there is a head of Times, with three branches, each having their own head Power, but this is not the same situation in the latter case.
A related question was mentioned here: default value for the 2nd argument in Power for pattern matching, and this is indeed more general and solves more cases, but I am still missing the cases where the term in my polynomial does not have every variable in it, for example: a+b+c /. a^i_. b^j_. c^k_. -> x^(i + j + k + 1) y^(i + k + 1) z^(k + 1) returns a+b+c rather than the desired x^2 y^2 z + x^2 y z + x^2 y^2 z^2.

a will only match  a^i_  if you specify a default argument of 1  to i: a /. a^(i_:1) -> something

I was about to mark this question as a duplicate of
Account for powers of 0 and 1 when defining function
but after a second thought I think it's not obvious enough, so let me post an answer:
a + a b + a b c + a^2 b /. (p1 : a^i_. : 1) (p2 : b^j_. : 1) (p3 : c^k_. : 1) -> 
  x^(i + j + k + 1) y^(i + k + 1) z^(k + 1)

(* x^2 y^2 z + x^3 y^2 z + x^4 y^3 z + x^4 y^3 z^2 *)

Notice the i/j/k in left hand side has actually become Sequence[] in right hand side. Minimal example illustrating the behavior:
aaah /. (coef : f[x_] : 1) aaah :> x

(* Sequence[] *)

