Is it possible to allow for zero match for pattern a_ when using a_*x?
Lets say the input is always an expression of the form   $a x+b y+c y^2$, where one or more terms can be missing. i.e. $a$ can be zero, or $b$ can be zero, or $c$ can be zero, or $a,b$ both can be zero, and so on. So if my math is correct, there are 8 possible cases
0
a*x
a*x + b*y
a*x + c*y^2
a*x + b*y + c*y^2
b*y
b*y + c*y^2
c*y^2

I want to use one pattern to find $a,b,c$. But it is not possible to use single pattern. If I write
expr=3*x + y + 99 y^2
expr/. a_.*x + b_. y + c_.*y^2 :>{a,b,c}

it gives correctly
{3, 1, 99}

Because all three terms are there. If one is missing, then ofcourse it will not match.
So one is forced to write  8 different patterns for each possible case of input.
It will be nice if there is a way to tell Mathematica to match on pattern a_.*x + b_. y + c_.*y^2 allowing for a_ or b_ or c_ to match zero. So given
expr=3*x + 99 y^2
expr/. a_.*x + b_. y + c_.*y^2 :> {a,b,c} 

Will give
{3,0,99}

And if given
expr=99 y^2
expr/. a_.*x + b_. y + c_.*y^2 :> {a,b,c} 

Will give
{0,0,99}

But now it does not work, since the corresponding terms are missing in the input.
Is there a way to do this pattern matching using single pattern instead of having to enumerate each possible expression input?
I tried using the default   b_:0 *y trick but it did not work
expr = 3*x + 99 y^2;
expr /. a_.*x + (b_ : 0)* y + c_.*y^2 :> {a, b, c}

Basically my question is how to do this without having to try each possible alternative in the input one by one until a match is found.
ps. I know for this specific example, I can use other ways to find coefficients of this multivariable polynomial without using patterns. But I am asking about using a single pattern.
I checked if there was similar question before but did not find one. If there is, feel free to close this one in this case.
V 14.1

Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/308082/1871 (Oh, lericr has posted an answer based on this idea. )

@xzczd I should have done a search first.

Okay, this is kind of jenky, so maybe you can make it more elegant.
rule = 
  ((aa : ((a : _ : 1)*x) : 0) + 
   (bb : ((b : _ : 1)*y) : 0) + 
   (cc : ((c : _ : 1)*y^2) : 0)) :> 
  {If[aa === 0, 0, a], If[bb === 0, 0, b], If[cc === 0, 0, c]}

3*x + 1 y + 99 y^2 /. rule
(* {3, 1, 99} *)

3*x + 99 y^2 /. rule
(* {3, 0, 99} *)

99 y^2 /. rule
(* {0, 0, 99} *)

3*x + 1 y /. rule
(* {3, 1, 0} *)


@leiricr Somewhat simplified rule would be rule = ((aa : (_.*x) : 0) + (bb : (_.*y) : 0) + (cc : (_.*y^2) :0)) :> ({aa, bb, cc}/.x|y->1) a bit of a hack though.

Extend my comment to an answer. This question is strongly related to
How can I write a single pattern for replacement for a nonlinear change of variables
And lericr has already given a good answer. The following solution is similar to lericr's. I just to illustrate some interesting features:
lst = {0, a x, a x + b y, a x + c y^2, 
          a x + b y + c y^2, b y + y^2, b y + c y^2, c y^2};
rule = (p1 : a_. x : 0) + (p2 : b_. y : 0) + 
       (p3 : c_. y^2 : 0) :> {Plus@a, Plus@b, Plus@c};

lst /. rule

(* {0, {a, 0, 0}, {a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}, 
       {a, b, c}, {0, b, 1}, {0, b, c}, {0, 0, c}} *)

Oops, the 0 case isn't handled, but this isn't handled by lericr's solution, either, so let it be. This answer has made use of the following features:
aaaa /. aaaa + (term : a_ x : 0) :> a
(* Sequence[] *)

Plus[]
(* 0 *)


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = {0, a*x, a*x + b*y, a*x + c*y^2, a*x + b*y + c*y^2, b*y, b*y + c*y^2, c*y^2};

coef[expr_] := Coefficient[expr /. y^2 -> z, #] & /@ {x, y, z}

coef /@ expr

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}, {a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}, {a, b, c}, {0, b, 0}, {0,
   b, c}, {0, 0, c}} *)

Edit: Or, slightly simpler
coef2[expr_] := Coefficient[expr, #] & /@ {x, y, y^2}

coef2 /@ expr

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}, {a, b, 0}, {a, 0, c}, {a, b, c}, {0, b, 0}, {0,
   b, c}, {0, 0, c}} *)


Thanks, but I know I can use the command coefficient. I said  I can use other ways to find coefficients of this multivariable polynomial without using patterns  so I was looking for solution using pattern.
